# Circular NIM Game

Tags: java

Trying to change this code, so that it will play the nim game like this:

```
01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09 
20                              10     
19  18  17  16  15  14  13  12  11
```

So far, it prints like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7.
```

---

This is the code:

I know it's clunky code, but i'm still learning.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println("Let's play the NIM game!");   
    TheNimGame game = new TheNimGame();  
    //Rows rows1 = new Rows();        
    game.StartGame();
}
```

TheNimGame.java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 * Created by SimonBlixenkrone on 21/10/2015.
 */
public class TheNimGame {
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );
    private ArrayList < Player > players = new ArrayList < Player > ();
    private ArrayList < Rows > rows = new ArrayList < Rows > ();
    private int defaultValueForRows = 3;
    //private int maxNumberOfObjectsInRow = 5;
    private int maxNumberOfObjectsInRow = 10;

    public void SetNumberOfRows(int numberOfRows) {
        defaultValueForRows = numberOfRows;
    }

    public void StartGame() {
        // set game
        populateRows();

        //add players
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter name of player " + i + ": ");
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setName(scanner.nextLine());
            players.add(player);
        }

        //run the game
        while (true) {
            printRows();
            takeTurn(players.get(0));
            if (gameover() == true) {
                System.out.println(players.get(0) + " lost the game");
                break;
            }
            printRows();
            takeTurn(players.get(1));
            if (gameover() == true) {
                System.out.println(players.get(1) + " lost the game");
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    private void printRows() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(rows.get(i));
        }
    }

    // this methods put a max number of obj in the first row and the one les in the next...
    private void populateRows() {
        for (int i = 0; i < defaultValueForRows; i++) {
            Rows r = new Rows();
            r.setNumberOfObjects(maxNumberOfObjectsInRow - i);
            rows.add(r);
        }
    }

    private boolean gameover() {
        /*for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++)
        {
            if (rows.get(i).getNumberOfObjects() > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;*/

        for (Rows row: rows) {
            if (row.getNumberOfObjects() > 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void takeTurn(Player player) {
        System.out.println(player + ": Which row do you want to take obejcts from?");
        int rowNumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        Rows row = rows.get(rowNumber - 1);

        System.out.println(player + ": How many object do you want to remove?");
        int numberOfObjects = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        if (player.removeObjects(row, numberOfObjects) == false) {
            takeTurn(player);
        }

    }

}
```

Rows.java

```
package com.company;

/**
 * Created by SimonBlixenkrone on 21/10/2015.
 */
public class Rows {
    private int numberOfObjects = 20;
    public int numberInRows = 0;

    public int getNumberOfObjects() {
        return numberOfObjects;
    }

    public void setNumberOfObjects(int numberOfObjects) {
        this.numberOfObjects = numberOfObjects;
    }

    public boolean removeObjects(int numberOfObjects) {
        if (this.numberOfObjects >= numberOfObjects) {
            this.numberOfObjects -= numberOfObjects;
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        //        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
            //s = s + "|";
            s = s + numberInRows+++" ";
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by SimonBlixenkrone on 21/10/2015.
 */
public class Player {
    private String name;
    //private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void enterName(Scanner scanner) {
        setName(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

    public boolean removeObjects(Rows rows, int numberOfObjects) {
        if (rows.removeObjects(numberOfObjects)) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " removed " + numberOfObjects + " objects");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not possible! try again");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj i tried mate, but it cuts some of the code into regular text, and some of it as code. Can you still give it a try? Cheers.

Comment: @AndyTurner changed it for your pleasure.

Comment: done. You had special characters in the code

Comment: If you are asking about how to print the numbers in a "circle", please cut the code down just to the bit which prints the numbers. http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for editing the code properly @YassinHajaj

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, that's exactly what i'm asking. As i recall (because i didn't code the whole thing myself), i think that some of the public methods are required in more parts of the code, to print out the numbers. So i'm not quite sure which parts to cut away.

Comment: @YassinHajaj do you have any clue? I would really appreciate the help, or just a guess really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure we take the same class. Cause that's my assignment as well.
Excuse my still-poor practice and feel free to relegate methods to their relevant classes. Maybe that'll give you some idea of where I am headed. Still WIP though.

```
public class NimGame {

//instantiate scanner object
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

private ArrayList<Integer> numbersArray = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();




public void startGame() {

    fillArrayList(20);
    printArrayListAsCircle();
    //add players
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter name of Player " + (1 + i) + ": ");
        Player player = new Player();
        player.setName(scanner.nextLine());
        players.add(player);
    }

    //run!!!
    while (true) {
        takeTurn(players.get(0));
        if (gameOver() == true) {
            System.out.println(players.get(0) + " lost the game");
            break;
        }
        printArrayListAsCircle();

        takeTurn(players.get(1));
        if (gameOver() == true) {
            System.out.println(players.get(0) + " lost the game");
            break;
        }
        printArrayListAsCircle();

    }
}

private void fillArrayList(int i) {
    //populate arrayList
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        numbersArray.add(j);
    }
}


//worked on this forever, trying (and failing) to implement foreach-loops, while-loops, simple for-loops.
//the result is... not pretty but performs well enough!
//most problems arose with printing the middle part and I must've tried 30 versions until this one worked.
//first I introduce two variables, one 'end'-point and one 'pivot'-point at which to 'wrap' the arraylist around.
//the ascending row is straightforward. run print() on all indices up to but not including the halfwayNumber.
//middle row: i honestly struggle to understand how I arrived there. So much debugging last night I lost it. It works though...
//descending row: analogue to ascending row, run print() on all indices DOWN to the halfwayNumber
public void printArrayListAsCircle() {
    int size = numbersArray.size();
    int halfwayNumber = size / 2;

    int i = 0;
    // Ascending row
    while (i < halfwayNumber-1) {
        print(numbersArray.get(i));
        i++;
    }

    // Middle row
    System.out.println();
    print(numbersArray.get(numbersArray.size()-1));
    for (int j = -1; j < halfwayNumber*2; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    print(numbersArray.get(halfwayNumber-1));
    i = size-2;
    System.out.println();

    // Descending row
    while (i >= halfwayNumber ) {
        print(numbersArray.get(i));
        i--;
    }
    System.out.println();
}

//my print() method. contains some formatting to make the top and bottom row align nicely. at least at the first iteration.
private void print(Integer i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}

//my new gameOver() method. short and sweet
private boolean gameOver() {
    return numbersArray.size() == 0;
}


//takeTurn() method, changed things around a bit
private void takeTurn(Player player) {
    System.out.println(player + ": please enter a start number");
    int startNumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println(player + ": please enter an end number");
    int endNumber = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    removeNumbers(startNumber, endNumber);

}

//this took a while and some trial and error, but in the end I came up with an algorithm that works:
//for-loop cycles through the arraylist 'size' times (-> this how often it cycles is dependent on the flexible size of the arraylist)...
// ...and for each iteration increments i to arrive at the next index UNLESS...
//...it finds an index where both if-conditions are found to be true. then i is removed.
//To ensure that ALL numbers in between startNum and endNum are removed as well i is then decremented...
//... because of the arraylist shrinking and assigning new indices to the elements 'shuffled to the left'.
private void removeNumbers(int startNumber, int endNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.size(); i++) {
        if (numbersArray.get(i) >= startNumber && numbersArray.get(i) <= endNumber) {
            numbersArray.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: that's amazing. Works like a charm. I'm sincerely impressed, and you sir, you will receive my vote of the day.